# belts and balls, correct size of holes

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

I'm working on a robot that has to transport a set of balls up at a 60 degrees angle. In order to do this I want to use a belt system with holes in it. Now my question is how big do these holes have to be for this situation to be stable? I know I probably have to use the fact that this situation is somehow stable if force vector starting from the centre of mass (in the middle of the ball) remains within the hole. But does anybody know how to properly calculate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, this is the picture you have in mind (in this diagram, the hole is just a little bit bigger than it needs to be):

[image]

In the limit, the size of the hole that *just* works has a diameter

$$d = 2 r \sin(60˚)$$

as should be obvious from looking at the picture.

Comment: This is indeed correct so that means that I should look for a hole of 43.3 mm or 45mm with safety margins.

Comment: "look for a hole of 43.3 mm" - that depends on the size of the balls... you never said :-), but from your comment I gather they are 50 mm in diameter. In which case your calculation is correct.

Comment: Ah yes I forgot to mention the size of the balls but they are indeed 50mm